# ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden when trying cross account copy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I am doing a cross account copy of s3 objects. When I am trying to copy files from source bucket to destination bucket I am getting the error **ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden**
I am getting error at line **s3_object.download_fileobj(buffer)**

```
    final_df=pd.DataFrame() 
for file in files1: 
# file=file.split('/')[-1]
    bucket = 'source bucket'
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3_object = s3.Object(bucket,file)
    s3_object.download_fileobj(buffer)
    df = pd.read_parquet(buffer)
    print(file)
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    file=file.split('/')[-1]
    print(file)
    final_df=pd.concat([final_df,df],sort=False)
```

Files1 is the list of all parquet files in the bucket

Answer (score 1):

The issue here may be with this being a cross account copy. You may need to set up an IAM role to ensure that both accounts have permission.

As found in https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/, along with other troubleshooting options,

> For ongoing cross-account permissions, create an IAM role in your
> account with permissions to your bucket. Then, grant another AWS
> account the permission to assume that IAM role. For more information,
> see Tutorial: Delegate access across AWS accounts using IAM roles. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html)

Comment: Yes I have set up an IAM role and source bucket and destination buckets have added it to the trust relationships. The source bucket has given list, get and   decrypt permissions. The destination bucket has added put permissions.